# Detect File System Working in Android

Tags: android, filesystems, ubifs

I need your help.

I need to know the File System used by one Android Device,
How detect if is YAFFS or UBIFS.

Thank you.

Best Regards,

Bernal

Answer (score 1):

I actually stumbled across this question while finding a way to transfer my photos without using HTC Sync Manager, but you might find this helpful:

1. Install an ssh server, e.g. [SSHDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid&hl=en) on the device
2. Once that's installed, start an ssh server. On a computer, ssh into it using the information given in the SSHDroid app:

   ```
   $ ssh root@<ip address> -p <port number>
   ```

   It will take a while. When it asks you `Are you sure you want to continue connecting?`, say `yes`. Then, when it prompts you for the password, enter `admin`.
3. Once you're ssh'd into the Android, run:

   ```
   $ mount
   ```

You will get an output similar to this:

```
~/data/berserker.android.apps.sshdroid/home $ mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (ro,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
none on /acct type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpuacct)
tmpfs on /mnt/asec type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000)
tmpfs on /mnt/obb type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000)
none on /dev/cpuctl type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpu)
none on /dev/timer_group type cgroup (rw,relatime,timer_slack)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p33 on /system type ext4 (ro,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p35 on /data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p34 on /cache type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p26 on /devlog type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p17 on /firmware_radio type vfat (ro,relatime,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,allow_utime=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=lower,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p18 on /firmware_q6 type vfat (ro,relatime,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,allow_utime=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=lower,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p19 on /firmware_wcnss type vfat (ro,relatime,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,allow_utime=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=lower,errors=remount-ro)
DxDrmServerIpc on /data/DxDrm/fuse type fuse.DxDrmServerIpc (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
htcfs on /data/htcfs type fuse.htcfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
/dev/block/vold/179:36 on /storage/sdcard0 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro,discard)
/dev/block/vold/179:36 on /mnt/secure/asec type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro,discard)
tmpfs on /storage/sdcard0/.android_secure type tmpfs (ro,relatime,size=0k,mode=000)
```

I don't know much about Android file system structure, but according to [this article](http://techblogon.com/android-file-system-structure-architecture-layout-details/), the `/system` partition contains the entire Android OS. I have a line like this in the output of `mount`:

```
/dev/block/mmcblk0p33 on /system type ext4 (ro,noatime,data=ordered)
```

So it's likely you will too. Also, I guess I have ext4 as my file system type.

Of course, you could have done all of this using a terminal emulator app, but that's a whole lot of output to parse, so you're better off ssh'ing from a bigger screen.

Comment: The *linux* supported filesystems are also in `/proc/filesystems`.  Usually, multiple *flash filesystems* will not be put in the same kernel image.

Comment: You may not have to SSH. You can just run `adb shell mount` on a computer connected to an Android device.